# What's wrong when I use ImageApplyIndexed?

Tags: image-processing

I am reading a ebook called [*Basic image processing in Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=8299) which can download free in the iBooks.
   In the page 114,it introduce a function `ImageApplyIndexed`.

```
i = ConstantImage[Black, {50, 50}];
{width, height} = ImageDimensions@i;
Clear[f];
f[pixel_, pos_] := 
Module[{dis = Norm[{width/2, height/2} - pos]}, 
pixel + dis/Norm[Min[width/2, height/2]]];
ImageApplyIndexed[f, i]
```

output:
[image]

But if I change the ImageSize of i:

```
 i = ConstantImage[Black, {100, 50}];
```

output:[image]

I don't know why the center of the black circle not in the center of the image?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32377/242

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageApplyIndexed` passes an *index* to your function, not *X/Y coordinates*, i.e. a list containing the row index and the column index (in that order). So you need to you `Norm[{height/2, width/2} - pos`. Because `height` is the number of rows, and `width` is the number of columns.