# Get an array of coordinates of the edges of an image

Tags: image-processing, image

[Rick Sanchez from Rick and Morty](https://www.google.com/search?q=rick+sanchez&espv=2&biw=1275&bih=668&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5rqHj58PKAhUCPj4KHT38BkkQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=rick+sanchez+rick+and+morty&imgrc=mK-SW1-AlvHChM%3A)

How can I get an array of coordinates of the edge of Rick in order from left to right? I want to make my delta robot draw images.

Additionally, I know that it is possible for Wolfram Alpha to generate a fairly long parametric equation if you ask it to for example "Draw Dratini", is there any way to get an array of coordinates from this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you need, but perhaps the following will help you get started.

First, import the picture:

```
img = Import["https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/rickandmorty/images/d/dd/Rick.png/revision/latest?cb=20131230003659"]
```

[image: figure]

Then find the outer edge:

```
edge = EdgeDetect@ColorQuantize[img, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, find the position of white pixels in the edge image:

```
edgepoints = Position[ImageData[edge], 1]

(* Out:

{{1, 85}, {1, 88}, {1, 89}, {2, 85}, {2, 89}, {2, 90}, {3, 85}, {3, 90}, ...}

*)
```

If you want only some of those points, then you can pick e.g. every other point from those results:

```
edgepoints[[1 ;; All ;; 2]]
```

Comment: If I want half as many points, would I change that 1 to a different number?

Comment: @Jenny No, the $1$ directs position to find the white pixels in the image, that are represented by a 1 value. If you want half as many points, you could pick e.g. every other point from the result (see edit).

Comment: Note that `Position[ImageData[...]]` returns *indices*, not *coordinates*. (The distinction is a bit confusing in MMA image processing, see for example: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104047/242). Use `PixelValuePositions[edge, 1]` to get the *coordinates*. Rule of thumb: If you want to manipulate the raw array returned by `ImageData`, use indices. If you want to draw something over the image using e.g. `Show`, use coordinates

Comment: @nikie Ha! Excellent point! I had not realized that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Perhaps you could keep points with density proportional to the curvature.See @nikie's answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95425/can-i-get-the-curvature-at-any-point-of-a-random-curve/95442#95442